# leer secuencialmente archivo Json multi-nivel generado con Newtonsoftjson core

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-core

Soy nuevo con Javascript y tengo un archivo JSON generado con NewtonSoft desde .net Core Razor Pages que posteriormente leo secuencialmente desde una función JQuery. El problema es que sólo reconoce el primer nivel de anidamiento, es decir, si pongo console.log(cats.length) sólo muestra 2 registros y no se cómo acceder a los niveles más internos.
A continuación pongo el contenido del archivo JSON y el javascript que lo lee y que muestra el siguiente resultado:

2

CATEGORIA 1

CATEGORIA 2

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Este es el archivo JSON generado: (He acomodado los niveles internos para que ocupe menos líneas)

```js
[
  {
    "CatId": 1, "Descrip": "CATEGORIA 1", "Nivel": 1,
    "SubCats": [
      { "SubCatId": 101, "Descrip": "SUBCAT 1", "Nivel": 2, "CatId": 1,
        "Motivos": [
          { "MotId": 10101, "Descrip": "MOTIVO 1", "Nivel": 3, "SubCatId": 101 },
          { "MotId": 10102, "Descrip": "MOTIVO 2", "Nivel": 3, "SubCatId": 101 }
        ]
      },
      { "SubCatId": 102, "Descrip": "SUBCAT 2", "Nivel": 2, "CatId": 1,
          "Motivos": [
            { "MotId": 10201, "Descrip": "MOTIVO 3", "Nivel": 3, "SubCatId": 102 },
            { "MotId": 10202, "Descrip": "MOTIVO 4", "Nivel": 3, "SubCatId": 102 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "CatId": 2, "Descrip": "CATEGORIA 2", "Nivel": 1,
    "SubCats": [
      { "SubCatId": 201, "Descrip": "SUBCAT 3", "Nivel": 2, "CatId": 2,
        "Motivos": [
          { "MotId": 20101, "Descrip": "MOTIVO 5", "Nivel": 3, "SubCatId": 201 },
          { "MotId": 20102, "Descrip": "MOTIVO 6", "Nivel": 3, "SubCatId": 201 },
          { "MotId": 20103, "Descrip": "MOTIVO 7", "Nivel": 3, "SubCatId": 201 },
        ]
      },
      { "SubCatId": 202, "Descrip": "SUBCAT 4", "Nivel": 2, "CatId": 2,
        "Motivos": [
          { "MotId": 20201, "Descrip": "MOTIVO 8", "Nivel": 3, "SubCatId": 202 },
          { "MotId": 20202, "Descrip": "MOTIVO 9", "Nivel": 3, "SubCatId": 202 },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Este es el código que lee el archivo JSON generado:

```js
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("/json/categorias.json", function (cats) {
            console.log(cats.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
                console.log(cats[i].Descrip);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Soluciobado !!!

```js
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("/json/categorias.json", function (cats) {
            for (var c = 0; c < cats.length; c++) {
                console.log(cats[c].CatId + ". " + cats[c].Descrip);

                for (var s = 0; s < cats[c].SubCats.length; s++) {
                    console.log(cats[c].SubCats[s].SubCatId + ". " + cats[c].SubCats[s].Descrip);

                    for (var m = 0; m < cats[c].SubCats[s].Motivos.length; m++) {
                        console.log(cats[c].SubCats[s].Motivos[m].MotId + ". " + cats[c].SubCats[s].Motivos[m].Descrip);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```